# ポインタの配列を利用したい

Tags: swift

```
private var test1: Int = 0
private var test2: Int = 0
private var test3: Int = 0

private var testArray: [Int] {
    get {
       return [test1, test2, test3]
    }
}
```

上記とすることで配列定義できることを教えていただいたのですが、
ポインターの配列とすることはできないのでしょうか。
下記のようではだめでした。

```
private var testArray: [UnsafePointer<Int>] {
    get {
       return [&test1, &test2, &test3]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swiftでは`&`記号は"address of"演算子ではなく、単にinoutパラメータであることを明示する(それによって関数呼び出しで値が変更される可能性があることをプログラマーに意識させるという効果があります)だけのもので、関数(メソッド含む)呼び出し以外では、ポインターを取得することはできません。

関数呼び出しなら良いんでしょということでこんな関数を使うことができるんですが、

```
    private var testArray: [UnsafePointer<Int>] {
        get {
            return withUnsafePointers(&test1, &test2, &test3) {
                test1Ptr, test2Ptr, test3Ptr in
                return [test1Ptr, test2Ptr, test3Ptr]
            }
        }
    }
```

基本的にwith...Pointer系の関数やメソッドではクロージャーにポインターとして渡される値はそのクロージャーを実行している間しか有効性が保障されないと考えるべきで、上記と全く同じコードが、`test1`, `test2`, `test3`の宣言された場所によっては全く期待通りに動かないこともあります。超要注意の記法で、どうしてもポインターでなければいけないという場合以外には使わないようにしてください。
(とは言ってもCやObjective-CのAPIを使おうと思うと「どうしてもポインター」と言う場合にはちょくちょく遭遇するんですが。とにかく「単にポインターを取り出すイディオム」的な軽い気持ちでは`with...Pointer`を使わないようにしてください。)

(追記)
コメントにあるaddObserverでのcontext引数の指定の仕方、最近のAppleのサンプルコードによく見られる形はこんなものです。(既にご存知かも知れませんが。)
グローバル変数として:

```
private var nantokaContext = 0 //当然Intになる
//...addObjserverに必要な数だけ繰り返し
```

同じファイルのとあるクラスのとあるメソッドの中:

```
        anObject.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: nantokaKey, options: [], context: &nantokaContext)
        //その他いろいろのaddObserverも同様
```

数が多くなるとこの部分をループにして、と思われるのも無理はありませんが、Appleのサンプルコードにはそんな例を見たことはありません。addObserverでのcontextの指定の仕方については、また興味と必要に応じて別件としてお尋ねください。

Comment: KVO監視をする際のaddObserver()のcontext引数への設定値をループで指定できないものかと模索していたのですが、今回は数も少ないのでやめておこうと思います。まだちゃんとわかっていないことが多すぎて、動いたからという感じで進めるのは危険と思いました。
ポインタの扱い難しいです。

Comment: CやObjective-Cのベテランでも(だからこそ、の場合も多い)Swiftのポインタには戸惑うことが多いようです。とりあえず、最近のAppleのサンプルコードによくあるcontextの書き方を回答に追記しておきますので、お時間があるときにご覧ください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！
最後に記載くださったとおり、数が増えるにつれ、ループ使えないのかな・・・と思った次第でした。現状は追記していただいた方法で羅列して記載することにしております。
大変勉強になりました！